# PHP & MySQL rating script page problem?

Tags: php, mysql

I found this script on about.com which I'm trying to learn from on how to create a rating system but the script for some reason wont count a vote when the link is clicked and will send me to a page that says not found. The page should just reload to itself and count the vote>

I was wondering how can I fix this problem? And what part of the code do I need to change and where?

Below is how the page looks like that I'm sent too.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /New was not found on this server.
```

Here is the script below.

```
<?php
// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sitename") or die(mysql_error());



//We only run this code if the user has just clicked a voting link
if ( $mode=="vote")
{

//If the user has already voted on the particular thing, we do not allow them to vote again $cookie = "Mysite$id";
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie]))
{
echo "Sorry You have already ranked that site <p>";
}

//Otherwise, we set a cooking telling us they have now voted
else
{
$month = 2592000 + time();
setcookie(Mysite.$id, Voted, $month);

//Then we update the voting information by adding 1 to the total votes and adding their vote (1,2,3,etc) to the total rating
mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total = total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $id");
echo "Your vote has been cast <p>";
}
} 



//Puts SQL Data into an array
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vote") or die(mysql_error());

//Now we loop through all the data
while($ratings = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{

//This outputs the sites name
echo "Name: " .$ratings['name']."<br>";

//This calculates the sites ranking and then outputs it - rounded to 1 decimal
if($ratings['total'] > 0 && $ratings['votes'] > 0) {
    $current = $ratings['total'] / $ratings['votes'];
}
else{
     $current = 0;
}
echo "Current Rating: " . round($current, 1) . "<br>";

//This creates 5 links to vote a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 rating for each particular item
echo "Rank Me: ";
echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=1&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 1</a> | ";
echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=2&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 2</a> | ";
echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=3&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 3</a> | ";
echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=4&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 4</a> | ";
echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=5&id=".$ratings['id'].">Vote 5</a><p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Rating must be a popular topic.  I noticed 5 questions related to building rating system with php and mysql on SO in the past 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` ? Does it contain a space? You need to put quotes around the href value, and encode all HTML entities (such as &), so the last lines become like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=5&...").\"">Vote</a>";
```

Comment: You should use the `urlencode` function there, rather than `htmlentities` function. And you should not include the query string, because the `?` and `&` would be encoded to, invalidating the GET data it is supposed to be sending.

Comment: What do you mean not include the query string? sorry for being ignorant I'm new to this.

Comment: Atli is saying that your last line should be more like this: `echo "<a href=\"".urlencode($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?mode=vote&voted=5&...".\"">Vote</a>";` The logic behind that is that `urlencode()` in the example above will encode the ? and & characters to their ASCII (I think?) equivalents, rendering them useless for PHP.

Comment: I tried that and it now turns my reguralr URL from `http://localhost/new file/8.php` to `http://localhost/new file/%2Fnew+fileProject%2F8.php?mode=vote&voted=2&id=3`

Comment: @Atli: I think you're confusing two things. (Actually he needs to do *both*, and we're each describing different ones). Step one is to `urlencode` the GET parameters, which is needed in case `$ratings['id']` contains f.i. = or ?. Step two is to encode the characters that have a special meaning in HTML (in a properly encoded URL, I think the only one that could be left is &).

Answer (score 0):

from the php documentation:

The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the address http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar would

just erase that thing and write the path to the script by yourself.